# Which cygwin package to install?

Tags: installation, cygwin, search, packages

I wanted to do some floating point math and realized that some bc utility is necessary. Where is the map of utilities to the cygwin packages that contain them?

Please note that using cygwin installer search is not usable because searching for "bc" produces too much results.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the top left corner there's a button "View" that lets you cycle through different display modes for the list. In mode "Full", you get an expanded list, where "bc" is right at the top.

Also, you could just expand the "Math" node, where "bc" is the first entry as well.

Finally, there's the searchable [Cygwin Package List](http://cygwin.com/packages/).